# What is the most widely accepted EMF exposure limit?

Tags: electromagnetic, radiation

I know that there isn't a specific answer to this and different countries have different guidelines in regard to this. There are a couple cell-phone towers in my vicinity (one of which is some 15-20 meters away). I live in India and I filed a complaint with our Department of Telecommunications and just today, they came to my house and took various readings in and around it. Being new to this subject, most of the terms I found on the internet were alien to me. And I couldn't convincingly convert readings through Google. 
My question is as follows: their instrument showed the EMF readings to be around 2.8-3.8 mW/m2 (milliwatts per metre square) at various points around the house. Is this safe?  They told me that the limit imposed by the Indian government is 4.5 mW/m2. It would be great if someone could verify that as well. I know for a fact that Indian regulations for EMF radiation are much more stringent than the EU and the US. I want to stay in the 'extreme' safe side and it would be great to know how this reading compares to the average exposure levels and those in different countries. 
I know there isn't one set in stone, but I would like to know the generally accepted limit for EMF exposure.

Comment: There's no study that has ever shown harm from long term exposure the levels of electromagnetic radiation involved in cell phone use.  You are exposed to higher levels than what was measured everytime you use your bluetooth and wifi enabled cellphone.  Why are you worried about the mast 20m away?

Comment: Your previous question gave a lot of discussion and answers. Your basically looking for someone to throw out a number lower than your government but, do you really trust random people on the internet to make up a number?

Comment: @Bageletas I would be fine with not getting a number as long as people attest to the fact that the figures should be safe for my health. I don't trust random people on the internet, but I do trust the process of self-curation on Stack Exchange. Essentially everything that the top answers on my previous question provided me with I double-checked with the government officers today, and all of it was spot-on. You'd notice that my last question was some 9 months ago and was very different to what I am asking here.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that there were some cell towers near where you lived, however, they are unlikely to be providing much of a discernible signal (-90dBm is considered a 'good-ish' cell signal and corresponds to 1 one billionth of a milliwatt, mobile phones don't need much signal so there's no point having the tower waste power by blaring away at full power - that would drown out the received signal anyway). The vast majority of your detected EM radiation is likely from and commercial Radio or TV stations nearby. A cell tower might pump out a few tens of watts if it needed to talk to a far away phone, but a TV station could easily be dumping 50'000 watts into the air (megawatt class transmitters are not unheard of - The Fernsehturm Berlin TV tower was the first Wikipedia result for "TV tower" and that does... or used to do a million watts or +90dBm on channel 27 - one million trillion times more powerful than what you might call '2 bars of reception')

The electromagnetic spectrum is quite a crowded place and has many bands, we have
ELF (lightning, tectonic motion - yes that does generate some Electromagnetic energy) 50/60Hz from the mains (a hundred km of mains cable makes a good antenna)

HF/VHF which covers just about all common commercial radio and TV broadcasts (which are broadcast at power levels several thousand times stronger than that from cell towers - we don't hear about those though, strange isn't it?)

UHF which sports the TV channels that didn't fit in the VHF bands, some of the bands used by mobile phones are also in the UHF band (some are actually squashed *in between* TV channels)

Next comes the SHF band with phones, microwave ovens and GPS, wifi, bluetooth, cordless home phones, some garage door openers, wireless weather stations etc. at the lower end while satellite TV, some security motion detectors, SATCOM, RADAR (be it automotive, weather, military, aerospace etc.), most emergency and military radios along with the microwave repeaters used both by "on scene" news crews and by telecomms companies to bring telephones and internet to remote rural communities at the higher end.

Beyond that is the EHF band, more commonly knows as millimeterwaves and includes THz radiation which is really only used by radio astronomy at the moment (but may end up in airport scanners soon).

Now moving out of the radio realm and into the "light" bands we have Long Wave Infra Red (LWIR) which is just a fancy name for heat (but it's *still* EM radiation)

I'm sure you know how the rest of this goes (I may have left out a radio band or two somewhere but you get the idea)

The moral of this story is that A) the strongest EM source is probably a TV station and not a cell tower (by quite a wide margin) and B) the strongest sources of EM radiation have been running for far longer that cell phones have even existed, if Radio band EM was going to kill people... I think after a century someone would have noticed. It's the EM radiation in the visible band that you really have to worry about (and can be commonly found at levels of several *thousand* mW per m^2). If you have a microwave oven, it probably produces more EM on average than a cell phone unless you use your phone for hours everyday.

Comment: I see. The instrument for EMF readings would have caught radio band EM as well, right? If that is to be the case, the comparatively low reading would point to the fact that there aren't any of these higher-band transmissions around me. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Sorry, but I'm really paranoid about this stuff and the lack of 'conclusive' evidence doesn't help either.

Comment: Lack of conclusive evidence comes from the fact that you can't prove a negative.   It is far easier to show that something has a particular effect (provide causing effect, observe the result.) I cannot, however, conclusively prove that you do not have an invisible pink unicorn living in your house.  If you say there is one, all I can do is try to look for evidence that is there.  If I say "there's no unicorn poop in your house" doesn't prove anything because maybe unicorns don't poop.  You are trying to find an invisible pink unicorn with your search for conclusive evidence...

Comment: ... RF fields are safe.  There is no evidence that they are are harmful (exposing people or animals to them causes no observable effect.) Proving that they are not harmful requires you to counter every possible constellation of exposure strength, time, varying field strength, etc.  You could go at it until time itself ends, and still have doubts.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The SAR is a measure of the rate at which electromagnetic energy is absorbed in the body.

In Canada,  to ensure that thermal effects are avoided, safety factors have been incorporated into the exposure limits, resulting in whole-body-averaged SAR limits of 0.08 W/kg in **uncontrolled** and and 0.4 W/kg in **controlled-environments**.

What studies don't tell you that eyes are caterogenic to heat from RF even by  a few 'C  so the whole body average is meaningless. Now she has a earbud-mic set which is much safer. Proven from workers who were exposed to IR heat levels.  The 1st symptom for RF is bloodshot eyes.

The part they don't analyze well is that Cancer does not affect everyone the same. Nor do sub-ionization levels of RF on the brain and eyes affect everyone the same. So corrolation studies fail to isolate this sensitivity even if 1% are 100% at risk and 90% have a 1% risk of approved levels.

I know MRI scan levels are never publish but Radiologics know the correlation between SAR and resolution of each scan and the safe limit per person in a lifetime. But your Doctor never knows or asks and the Radiologist never tells. She used her cell phone or cordless phone for many hours in the same side where Meningitis started.

From personal experience with my wife I have some concerns on MRI [1mm] resolution scans and effects on olfactory and hearing after she got bacterial meningitis near left ear then cured with antibiotics, then months later after many CT+MRI scans in the process,  lost taste  and smell for extended periods in the following couple years for no explained reason by many specialists.

I have also seen RF tech's in the 70's calibrate 100W RF amps properly terminated but open case lid and maybe leaking a watt or so, get bloodshot eyes after a days work , that stop following week with safeguards for testing RF.

From the RF 3D Radiation plots of the brain ears and eyes, I have seen 20 yrs ago, I chose never to use a cell phone unless in emergency situations.

Now she has a earbud-mic set for cordless and cellphone which is **much** safer and has recovered 3 senses which had lapsed *after* her illness. although hearing loss started before.

But yet noone has controlled experimental data to prove anything detrimental in significant percentages. Perhaps because it is gene sensitive which scatters the data.

Comment: Will the person with -1 IQ pls leave a comment?

Comment: The output power of cellphones has declined over the decades, as the dense user community necessitates dense cell tower placement, which reduces the PathLosses and lets the handset become very low power.

Comment: Yes the first cell phones typically operated at a maximum power of 0.6 watts.   Newer phones typically operate at 0.2 watts. The most sensitive part of the body is the eyes over long term exposure. Although some people with ear infection may have lower immunity.